# How to retrieve multiple users data based on userid in meteor js?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-helper

I have created a chat message functionality. The message stores the userid of sender and receiver. How can I get other details of the user just based on the userid?

Is creating a Meteor method the best way or I have to create publish/subscribe pattern for it.

I want to avoid sending all users data to client side.

I tried creating a meteor method but I don't think its the best approach.

```
Meteor.methods({
getUserInfoById: function (usrId) {
    //console.log("BEGIN");
    //console.log(usrId);
    var user = Meteor.users.findOne(usrId);
    //console.log(user);
    //console.log("END");

    return user;
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a publisher (and also a subscriber) for the data about other users that you want a given user to see. You can restrict the fields returned using the `{fields: ...}` qualifier in the query.

This is a very common pattern. Using a method for this is an anti-pattern due to the extra round-trip delay for something you're likely to show quite often, i.e. another user's username or avatar.